# Whats wrong with my indentation/position of print or use of break? Python

Tags: python

Purpose: To create a code that can check a list of variables to see if they are prime numbers or not.

Problem: Upon running this code, for the value of 8 I will see `False` followed by `True`.

Question: Why am I seeing `False` then `True` when I just expect to see `False` because 8 is not a prime number?

1. Is it because I am using break wrongly?
2. Or is it because of where I put print? I placed it at that indentation because I wanted I to check if all values of `number % n!=0` before it returned `True`.

Code

```
def prime_number(x):
  for number in x:
    n = 2
    if number <=2:
      return False
    elif number > 2:
      while n < number -1:
        if number % n == 0:
          print False
          n+=1
          break
        elif number % n !=0:
          print number % n
          n +=1
      print True
print prime_number([8])
```

Comment: Either stick to printing results within the function, or have all avenues out of your function `return` some Boolean value. Otherwise `print prime_number([8])` is going to start printing `None` values too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below should work (although I haven't tried it). Firstly you should change your `print` statments to `return` statements. That way it will end the function once you reach the return statement. Because it automatically breaks out, there is no need for breaking or the adding of n. Also one minor problem in your post is that you have considered 2 to not be prime number but it is so you should remove the equals sign from that if statement. Since you're not returning any values, you shouldn't print the function. Instead simply call it.

```
def prime_number(x):
  for number in x:
    n = 2
    foundDivisor=False
    if number <2:
      print(False)

    elif number > 2:
      while n < number -1:
        if number % n == 0:
          foundDivisor=True
          print(False)
          break
        elif number % n !=0:
          print(number % n)
          n +=1
      if foundDivisor==False:
        print(True)
prime_number([8,11,2])
```

Output:

> False
>
> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3
>
> 1
>
> 5
>
> 4
>
> 3
>
> 2
>
> True
>
> True

I believe this is what you wanted.

Comment: I dont want to use return because if i were to unput a list of number and if the first number is not prime it will return false without checking the rest

Comment: Doing that makes it slightly more complicated. You need a variable to check if you've found a divisor yet. I have edited my answer to include this.

Comment: Omg yeah thats exactly what i wanted i to do but i dont really understand how inputting that divisor variable gets that answer =/ like 5 would still fall under the category of !=0 so how does it end up under if not divisor?

Comment: So we define a variable called `foundDivisor`. This is set to False originally meaning that no divisors of that number have been found yet. We then make that True only once we find a divisor. By the end, if no divisors have been found then `foundDivisor` is still False so it is prime and we output True.

Comment: Does it mean you assign a variable to each number in the list. If it is divisable by a certain number you change that variable to true.  If the number are not divisable and dont have that variable's actual value, it is placed under the if condition of not having the variable's actual value??? Thanks so much for the help btw!!! And why cant i use elif and can only use if?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're saying but yes I think you get the idea of what the variable is used for. In terms of the if (I assume you're talking about the `if not foundDivisor`), it cannot be elif because there are no other if statements before it. It is not dependent on any other if statements so it should be left as if not elif. Also, please vote up and accept the answer if you found it satisfactory.

Comment: sorry to intrude again but can i just confirm that if not founddivisor has the same meaning as if the variable founddivisor has a different value than before print X?

Comment: Edited :sorry but i dont think my interpretation is correct. What does the line "if not foundvariable" look for exactly?? Lets say x is 5 for example . sorry to intrude again but can i just confirm that if not founddivisor has the same meaning as if the variable founddivisor has a different value than before? If yes, print X.

Comment: I've changed that line of code to hopefully make it more understandable. It simply checks that it is false meaning no divisors have been found (so it is prime)

Answer (score 0):

The problems is in the if statement:

What it does is:
1.- Goes to the function prime_number and gets in the elif part of the if. As is divisible by 2, prints False and does the break (of the while)

2.- When the while finishes, you always print True

You should change your break with a return like this:

```
def prime_number(x):

  for number in x:
    n = 2
    if number <=2:
      return False

    elif number > 2:
      while n < number -1:
        if number % n == 0:
          print (False)
          n+=1
          return

        elif number % n !=0:
          print (number % n)
          n +=1

      print (True)

print (prime_number([8]))
```

If you change the indent of the print(True), you will print True for every try you make

Comment: I am sorry but why will it print true? Shouldnt it end there because there isnt another value in X for it to check against N? And I dont want to use return because if i were to input a list of number and if the first number is not prime it will return false without checking the rest

Comment: It prints true because the break it's for the while loop. So you finish that loop and go to the next instruction, in this case print (True). If you want to try it for another number you should take it out of the function

Comment: Isnt the print true instruction only applicable if x %n !=? At least thats what i intend for it to do